# Finding two different angle for the same 2 vector.

Tags: vectors

Let $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ be as following:$$\vec a=\vec i+2\vec j-2\vec k$$$$\vec b=\vec i-\vec j+\vec k$$
$$\vec c=\vec a\times \vec b=-3\vec k-3\vec j$$
$$\vec d=\vec b-\vec a=-3\vec j+3\vec k$$

I defined $\vec d$ like that because I want to use cosinus theorem to find angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ (let say $\phi$), purpose of defining $\vec c$ is obvious.

(i) To learn what $\phi$ is, let's apply cross product and its application that is finding areas:

$$|\vec c|=3\sqrt2=|a||b|\sin \phi=3\sqrt3\sin \phi$$
 so $$\phi=\arcsin \left(\dfrac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}\right)=0.955316618125$$

On the other hand,
(ii)

$$d^2=a^2+b^2-2|a||b|\cos \phi$$$$18=9+3-6\sqrt3\cos\phi$$$$\Rightarrow$$$$\phi=arccos\left(\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt3}\right)=2.18627603547$$ But $$arccos\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)=0.955316618125$$

Where am I wrong?, I've checked many times but didn't find the problem. Thanx in advanced.

Comment: I think it stems from the fact that the cross product formula is written entirely with magnitudes so you don't really have a sense of quadrant for these angles, wherein if you use the dot product definition instead you will see the same answer in your law of cosines.

Comment: The fact that $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = |a||b|\cos{\phi}$

Comment: yes yes I got it thanx.

Comment: but, again there is problem, $\vec a.\vec b=-3$ but $|a||b|\cos \phi=-3$ so $\arccos(-1/\sqrt3)\not= 0.95...$

Comment: Is there some reason to believe that the answer is $.95...$?

Comment: then cross product is wrong but how?

Comment: As far as I can tell it's because of the magnitudes and reference angles. But the dot product and your law of cosines are yielding the correct answer from what I can check, coincidentally Wolframalpha also agrees on the angle between them. I can't really check due to being on my phone right now but I feel that's the case

Comment: why cross product is making problem here

Comment: It's the domains and ranges of the inverse trig functions, the angle is larger than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so the arcsine yields the reference angle of $\pi-\phi$. This is why the dot product is better for this type of thing as arccosine has a range from $0$ to $\pi$

Comment: The cross product formula is not at fault. It gives $$3\sqrt 2 = 3\sqrt 3\sin \phi$$ which is true. Your mistake is thinking that this is equivalent to $$\phi = \arcsin \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}$$ There are two angles $\phi$ between $0$ and $\pi$ with $\sin \phi = \sqrt 2 /\sqrt 3$. One is $\approx 0.955$ and the other is $\approx 2.186$. But $\arcsin$ gives the lower one only.